# Any way to do "sticky folders" (or similar) w/ staged deployments in Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a legacy app that was ported to Azure Websites with about 25GB of local on-disk assets. When using staged deployments, we have to sync all of those assets over to the deployment slot prior to swapping, which is a bad time as they are spread over a few thousand folders. **I know that the best solution is to switch the local file storage over to blob storage**, which we're in the process of, but it is a slow undertaking while we learn the intricacies of blob storage.

Is there anything like sticky config settings (http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/11/azure-websites-slots/) but for folders? Alternatively, is there any way to attach an actual disk to a Website (so that we could drop all the files to say D:\ but it would not switch on swap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no sticky folders. The way staged deployments work is that each of your slots (production and staging slots) are actually two independent websites. When you say "swap" then it's just the host names and site names for the sites that get swapped.  Effectively it's just a pointer swap.

The sticky settings feature works by swapping those settings as well when you as for the swap.  It appears sticky because the settings sticks with the same site name, but in reality it's only the "sticky" settings that are being swapped.  That means if there were to be a sticky folder, during swap we would have to delete the files from site A and copy them to site B and vice versa.

You can't attach a disk to a website either. Good luck ramping up on blob storage.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I had a tiny sliver of hope that there was a undocumented feature hidden somewhere that I had missed, figured it couldn't hurt to ask. Blob storage it is!